# How to find a variable in matrices so both are equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Having two matrices:

$A = \left(\begin{matrix}36a & -170 - a \\ -2a - 144 & 26 \end{matrix}\right)$

$A^2 = \left(\begin{matrix}1298a^2 + 495a + 24480 & -36a^2 - 6146a - 4420 \\ -72a^2 - 5236a - 3744 & 2a^2 + 484a + 25156 \end{matrix}\right)$

I need to find $a$ so that $A = A^2$.
I've tried $A^2 - A = 0$ but it doesn't seem to be right.

I was hoping someone here would be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: It cannot be done. Where did you get the problem?

Comment: As part of a homework set.

Comment: The requirement is that the roots of the characteristic polynomial can only be $0$ or $1.$ You can choose $a$ so that one root is zero, but the second root is neither zero nor one. Again, you can choose $a$ to force one root to be  one, but the other is neither zero nor one. Look up "eigenvalue"

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$A^2=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} 1296\,{a}^{2}+ \left( -170-a \right) 
 \left( -2\,a-144 \right) &36\,a \left( -170-a \right) -4420-26\,a
\\ 36\, \left( -2\,a-144 \right) a-52\,a-3744&
 \left( -170-a \right)  \left( -2\,a-144 \right) +676\end {array}
 \right] 
$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint - however i already managed to find $A^2$ as i already tried $A^2 - A = 0$. I'll just update the question.

Comment: so you can solve your problem now?

Comment: No. I can't seem to get it right. I've even tried solving the four different equations like $A_{1,1} = A^2_{1,1}$ etc.. All giving way different results and none of them is making $A = A^2$

Comment: ok,let me try it

Comment: i got two complex values!

Comment: yes you have right not all $a$ are equal!

Comment: Yep, by solving $A_{1,1} = A^2_{1,1}$ i got $a = -112/649-(1/649) \cdot (4i) \cdot sqrt(495701) \vee a = -112/649+(1/649) \cdot (4i) \cdot sqrt(495701)$. However they are not the same for the other equations and does not seem make $A = A^2$. I'm not sure what else to do here :/